# MySQL syntax error [Left Join]

Tags: mysql, join, left-join

So i've got this query below and it's giving me a syntax error. I will show the error below the query.

Please check below:

```
SELECT g.fullname, g.id as guardian_id, g.email, g.email_2, s.title, s.domain, d.device_id as device, d.os, gf.booking_open_notified, gf.days_notified_7, gf.days_notified_3, gf.day_notified, s.id as school_id, p.firstname, p.surname 
FROM guardian as g
LEFT JOIN guardian_form as gf ON gf.school_id = g.school_id
LEFT JOIN school as s ON s.id = g.school_id 
LEFT JOIN school_design as sd ON sd.school_id = s.id 
LEFT JOIN device as d ON d.school_id = s.id AND d.guardian_id = g.id 
    (
        LEFT JOIN pupil as p ON p.school_id = s.id AND 
        (
            p.grade_id = gf.grade_id
            OR p.grade_id = gf.grade_id_2
            OR p.grade_id = gf.grade_id_3
            OR p.grade_id = gf.grade_id_4
            OR p.grade_id = gf.grade_id_5
            OR p.grade_id = gf.grade_id_6
            OR p.grade_id = gf.grade_id_7
            OR p.grade_id = gf.grade_id_8
            OR p.grade_id = gf.grade_id_9
            OR p.grade_id = gf.grade_id_10
        )
    ) OR (
        LEFT JOIN guardian_form_group as gfg ON gfg.guardian_form_id = gf.id
        LEFT JOIN pupil_group as pg ON pg.group_id = gfg.group_id
        LEFT JOIN pupil as p ON p.id = pg.pupil_id AND pg.school_id = s.id
    )
WHERE (
    gf.booking_open_notified != 1 
    OR gf.days_notified_7 != 1 
    OR gf.days_notified_3 != 1 
    OR gf.day_notified != 1 
)
AND gf.active = 1
AND sd.disable_parents_evening_notification_and_email = 0 
GROUP BY gf.id, p.id 
LIMIT 20
```

Error:

> Error SQL query: Documentation
>
> ```
> SELECT g.fullname, g.id as guardian_id, g.email, g.email_2, s.title,
> s.domain, d.device_id as device, d.os, gf.booking_open_notified,
> gf.days_notified_7, gf.days_notified_3, gf.day_notified, s.id as
> school_id, p.firstname, p.surname  FROM guardian as g LEFT JOIN
> guardian_form as gf ON gf.school_id = g.school_id LEFT JOIN school as
> s ON s.id = g.school_id  LEFT JOIN school_design as sd ON sd.school_id
> = s.id  LEFT JOIN device as d ON d.school_id = s.id AND d.guardian_id = g.id      
> (
>   LEFT JOIN pupil as p ON p.school_id = s.id AND 
>   (
>         p.grade_id = gf.grade_id
>         OR p.grade_id = gf.grade_id_2
>         OR p.grade_id = gf.grade_id_3
>         OR p.grade_id = gf.grade_id_4
>         OR p.grade_id = gf.grade_id_5
>         OR p.grade_id = gf.grade_id_6
>         OR p.grade_id = gf.grade_id_7
>         OR p.grade_id = gf.grade_id_8
>         OR p.grade_id = gf.grade_id_9
>         OR p.grade_id = gf.grade_id_10
>   )
> ) OR
> ```
>
> MySQL said: Documentation
>
> 1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use
>   near
>
> ```
> 'JOIN pupil as p ON p.school_id = s.id AND 
>     (
>         p.grade_id = gf.' at line 8
> ```

Comment: Incidentally, `LEFT JOIN x WHERE x =...` is the same as `INNER JOIN x`

Comment: And any time you find yourself with enumerated column names (above, say, 2), you can be sure that something's gone very, very wrong with your schema design.

Comment: i feel like it's the `(` you open before `LEFT` and is the whole construct with `JOIN... OR` even possible?

Answer (score 0):

Your syntax IS LIKE

```
SELECT listOfColumns FROM table1 LEFT JOIN table2 (LEFT JOIN table3) OR (LEFT JOIN table4)
```

Why are you trying TO USE 'OR' for joining ? This is not supported. Try improving your ON conditions if you want to filter out the tables

Comment: I'm trying to get the guardians/pupils which are link to the guardian_form which are either linked to grade_id or group